# sequence of Riemann-integral integrable functions that converges to 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Question: Prove or disprove the following statement.

If $\{f_n\}$ is a non-decreasing sequence of Riemann-integrable functions on $R = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ so that $f_n(x) \to 0$ for almost all $x \in R$, then $\lim_n \int_{R} f_n \, dx = 0.$

I believe this statement is false. However, I am not able to find a counterexample with $\lim_n \int_R f_n\, dx \neq 0$. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: What does “converges to $0$” mean in this context?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I made some edits to the question. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a counterexample:

Let $$f_n(x,y) = \begin{cases} n & x\in({0},\frac{1}{n}) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Clearly $f_n$ is non-decreasing. Moreover, $f_n(x,y)\rightarrow 0$ for all $(x,y)$, because for any $(x,y)$ if $x=0$ then $f_n(x,y)=0$ and otherwise there exists $n$ sufficiently large so that $\frac{1}{n}<x$ and then $f_n(x,y)=0$.

However, $\int_R f_n(x,y) dx = 1$ for all $n$ and so in particular does not vanish as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: I don't think $f_n$ is non-decreasing, because $f_1(\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2}) =1$ but $f_2(\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2})= 0$.

Comment: @L-JS non-decreasing does not mean increasing! If decreasing means "for every $x$ and $n$,  $f_{n+1}(x)\leq f_n(x)$", then non-decreasing means that this fails namely "**there exist** $x$ and $n$ with $f_{n+1}(x) > f_n(x)$".